# Doubt regarding $ F = BQv \sin \theta$

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, charge

In $ F = BQv \sin \theta$, is $v$ velocity acquired by charged particle after entering magnetic field or is it already moving with $v$ m/s and $F$ force acts on it after it enters magnetic field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the velocity $v$ comes from.

The equation tells us "*if* a charged particle has a velocity $v$ while it is at a location with magnetic field $B$ then *at that instant* it will feel a force $F=qBV\sin\theta$"

It doesn't tell us anything about the past or future. It doesn't tell us about the past because the equation only involves the value of the velocity *right now* and the value of the magnetic field *right now*. It doesn't tell us about the future because it doesn't tell us what other forces might be acting on the object.